# How to apply dynamic classes inside of v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

***Edited*** How do you dynamically set classes on multiple elements inside of a v-for? I cannot use a computed property because of the v-for, so I tried using a method passing the index of the element but that has not worked.

```
                    <div v-for="(pet,index) in pets"
                      :key="pet.id"
                      :index="index">
                      <v-row
                class="d-flex justify-center"
              >
                <v-col
                  cols="12"
                  sm="12"
                  md="12"
                  class="d-flex justify-center"
                >
                  <v-col cols="3">
                    <v-card
                      class="pa-2 text-center"
                      :class="premiumCoverage ? 'active' : 'plans'"
                    >
                      <v-card-title class="mb-3 primary--text d-flex justify-center">
                        <strong>${{ premiumPrice(0, index).toFixed(2) }}</strong>
                      </v-card-title>
                      <v-card-subtitle class="primary--text mb-3">
                        per month
                      </v-card-subtitle>
                      <v-card-text>$0 DEDUCTIBLE</v-card-text>
                      <v-card-text style="overflow-y: auto; height:150px">
                        The best choice for <br>planning for <br>unexpected vet bills.
                      </v-card-text>
                      <v-btn
                        outlined
                        class="mb-6 font-weight-bold"
                        :class="premiumCoverage ? 'selected' : 'select-btn'"
                        @click="coverageSelected('premium', 0, index)"
                      >
                        {{ premiumCoverage ? 'SELECTED' : 'SELECT' }}
                      </v-btn>
                    </v-card>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="3">
                    <v-card
                      class="pa-2 text-center"
                      :class="standardCoverage || noCoverage ? 'active' : 'plans'"
                    >
                      <v-card-title class="mb-3 primary--text d-flex justify-center">
                        <strong>${{ standardPrice(200, index).toFixed(2) }}</strong>
                      </v-card-title>
                      <v-card-subtitle class="primary--text mb-3">
                        per month
                      </v-card-subtitle>
                      <v-card-text>$200 DEDUCTIBLE</v-card-text>
                      <v-card-text style="overflow-y: auto; height:150px">
                        OUR MOST POULAR <br>CHOICE
                      </v-card-text>
                      <v-btn
                        outlined
                        class="mb-6 font-weight-bold"
                        :class="standardCoverage || noCoverage ? 'selected' : 'select-btn'"
                        @click="coverageSelected('standard', 200, index)"
                      >
                        {{ standardCoverage || noCoverage ? 'SELECTED' : 'SELECT' }}
                      </v-btn>
                    </v-card>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="3">
                    <v-card
                      class="pa-2 plans text-center"
                      :class="baseCoverage ? 'active' : 'plans'"
                    >
                      <v-card-title class="mb-3 primary--text d-flex justify-center">
                        <strong>${{ basePrice(700, index).toFixed(2) }}</strong>
                      </v-card-title>
                      <v-card-subtitle class="primary--text mb-3">
                        per month
                      </v-card-subtitle>
                      <v-card-text>$700 DEDUCTIBLE</v-card-text>
                      <v-card-text style="overflow-y: auto; height:150px">
                        A great choice to help<br>reduce your monthly <br>payment.
                      </v-card-text>
                      <v-btn
                        outlined
                        class="mb-6 font-weight-bold"
                        :class="baseCoverage ? 'selected' : 'select-btn'"
                        @click="coverageSelected('base', 700, index)"
                      >
                        {{ baseCoverage ? 'SELECTED' : 'SELECT' }}
                      </v-btn>
                    </v-card>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="3">
                    <v-card
                      class="pa-2 plans text-center"
                      :class="customCoverage ? 'active' : 'plans'"
                    >
                      <v-card-title class="mb-4 primary--text d-flex justify-center">
                        <strong>Customize <br>your price</strong>
                      </v-card-title>
                      <v-card-text>CUSTOM</v-card-text>
                      <v-card-text style="min-height:150px">
                        Choose a price that <br>works for you! Select <br>this option to <br>customize your <br>deductible.
                      </v-card-text>
                      <v-btn
                        outlined
                        class="mb-6 font-weight-bold"
                        :class="customCoverage ? 'selected' : 'select-btn'"
                        @click="coverageSelected('custom', 0, index)"
                      >
                        {{ customCoverage ? 'SELECTED' : 'SELECT' }}
                      </v-btn>
                    </v-card>
                  </v-col>
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
```

When the user clicks a select button, the card containing that button and that button itself have their styles changed to reflect the selection. All other cards and buttons have their styles set to default so that the card that is selected stands out from the group.

Comment: make a `selected` model (array), then on click push the item to it then you simply use `selected.includes(pet)`, then when unselect, do indexOf, slice etc on `selected` array, i.e maintain a separate model which holds selected values, if you put it on the object, pagination will also be a pain when you implement

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    {{ selected }}
    <button
      v-for="item in items"
      :key="item"
      @mousedown="selected = true"
      @mouseup="selected = false"
      :class="{ selected: selected, 'not-selected': !selected }"
    >
      {{ item }}
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, reactive } from "vue";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  setup() {
    const items = reactive(["btn1", "btn2", "btn2"]);
    const selected = ref(false);
    return {
      selected,
      items,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
.selected {
  background-color: blue;
}
.not-selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve here

Edit1:

What I would do in your case is to create 2 components:

- The "container" component that holds the array of pets and the v-for
- A "pet" component that show the specific pet

On each pet of pets I would add a property (boolean) that indicate if the pet is selected.

and on the "pet" component set the class based on that boolean.

Finally to add class based on a boolean look at the exemple I gave you.

Comment: I edited the question to include more information